# How to use standard state list from a Button in my TextView

Tags: android

I'm creating compund cotrol containing 3 clickable TextViews.
I made them focusable and now I want them change background in dependence of their focus state. 
I know that it is quite easy to create my own drawable state list resource to use it as the TextView backgroud.
But I want to use statndart state list (selector) like in a Button.

Unfortunately I don't know the ID of standart state list of the button.
Does any body know the ID to write it in the android:background attribute of my TextViews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "@android:drawable/btn_default" drawable as background of the TextView so it will set the default button background to the TextView.